# How do I count part of a string up to a specific character?

Tags: pascal

I have elements stored in an array, in the format `name#email`, I want to search the array by name, and then output the email only i.e what comes after the `#.`, For example, if the element is `donald#donald@hotmail.com` when I search by name Donald, the output should be `donald@hotmail.com`.

The idea I have is to subtract length(string) from the length(name). How do I count only upto #?

Answer (score 1):

To search for the position of a substring in pascal in a string, use the [Pos()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function.

In your case, the substring would consist of the name plus the `#` character.

---

A simple function to extract what comes after the name plus the `#` would look like:

```
function ExtractInfo( const searchName,data : String) : String;
var
 p : Integer;
begin
  p := Pos(searchName+'#',data); // Find position of name + '#' in data
  if (p > 0) then
    Result := Copy(data,p+Length(searchName)+1) // Copy after name and `#`
  else
    Result := '';
  // Note 1, if Result is not a valid way to assign the function result, 
  // use ExtractInfo instead.
  // Note 2, if only two parameters are not allowed in your pascal Copy function, 
  // add Length(data) as the third parameter.
end;
```

To test the function:

```
WriteLn(ExtractInfo('donald','donald#donald@hotmail.com'));
```